# Inferring underlying codes from surface manifestations - who said it?

Tags: reference-request, structuralism

In Anthony Giddens' The Constitution of Society, page 16, he writes:

> As conceptualized in structuralist and post-structuralist thought, on
> the other hand, the notion of structure is more interesting. Here it
> is characteristically thought of not as a patterning of presences but
> as an intersection of presence and absence; underlying codes have to
> be inferred from surface manifestations.

My question is:

Which sociologists or books under the umbrella of structuralist and post-structuralist thought introduced this idea. Where did it come from? I've heard a hint that it may be Derrida, and if so, I'm interested in knowing which book it came from as well.

Comment: "Underlying codes" and "surface manifestations" are of Giddens's own making, in the course of his project to adapt Derrida's différance and deconstruction to social theory. Giddens is more explicit about the relation to Derrida in his 1979 and 1987 articles, see [Ortmann's commentary](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-531-90921-9_6) on his project.